# Port Redirection To Domain Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, subdomain, port

I am using Cent OS 5.8 with kloxo.

I have a ruby application. When i start the application , by default it starts at port nos 3000. So to access dat i need to put domain.com:3000 .

This doesn't look good , so I decided to run mongrel at port nos 80.
now i am able to access domain.com

But now i want that the application shall run in a sub domain and there should be a different website running in my main domain.

I tried putting  code in httpd.conf and it didn't work.

Can any one help me on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx as a proxy to accomplish this. You can then run your apps on ports 3000, 3001 and 3002 (for example) and let nginx route the traffic based on the hostname requested. But I recommend you looking into [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) for production environments because it enables you to run applications like you're used to in an Apache or nginx environment. According to Phusion, it also outperforms Mongrel, but your mileage may vary of course.

Comment: Even I thought of using nginx. I cant compromise with mongrel. It is the only way for me. Could you please route me to the proper solution with nginx.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can use nginx as a proxy, but not as a webserver, but take a look at the example here that can help you set up nginx as a proxy to mongrel: http://wiki.nginx.org/RubyonRailsMongrel. Do mind that you will need to set up a cluster if the website is going to experience any kind of load. This is also used in the example I provided. Mind that going this way is a lot more work and will probably not perform as well as Passenger.

Comment: Will passenger allow me to redirect.. I mean i can achieve my target using passenger..? Guide me on that part...

Comment: Passenger will in this case replace Mongrel (when combined with nginx or Apache).

Comment: yeah... but how can i use redirections in passenger.?

Comment: What do you mean with redirection? Please read into Passenger, there are great guides available. You don't need to redirect anything to achieve your goals when you use Passenger. You can run multiple websites on port 80.

Comment: i need to call mongrel and run an instance in may be port nos 81 or 3000 and den redirect it to a domain. this is what i wanna knw..

Comment: Then look at the nginx guide I provided earlier, if you really want to use mongrel in production.